# Postman: calling API that requires client certificate always throws 403 Forbidden

Tags: postman, .net-6.0, iis-10

I have my API running under IIS 10. I have applied the server certificate to the site. In IIS I have also enabled SSL and I am requiring a client certificate.

The certificate has the full chain with password. In my postman request I am attaching the same certificate to my request but it always comes back 403 forbidden. If I remove the requirement for client certificate on IIS then postman request hits the API.

What am I missing? Additional folder permissions?
I already have IUSR, IIS_IUSR & the app pool

Or do I need to add something to web.confg ?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Could you provide detailed error message about 403? You can try using FRT to troubleshooting, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Its 403.16 after setting up FRT. That is strange I am sending over the exact same certificate thats on the server. And its a real certificate not some self signed thing.

Comment: Even though I had my certificate registered under the site in IIS I had to specifically import it into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder. Then the 403.16 went away. Thanks for your help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-403-forbidden-access-website